# How to make deb packages for my server?

Tags: makefile, installation, package, deb

I have a Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) install for my desktop, and I have two VPS servers that run Ubuntu (11.04 LTS) as well. I have PHP running on these servers using fcgi, but I want to upgrade to the lastest version of PHP (5.4.3) and include the modules that I need baked right in. It just so happens that the regular `./configure` script happens to include all of the things that I need. So from here, I want to make a deb package that I can use on my two VPS servers so that I can quickly install it using `apt-get install php`. What do I have to do in order for this to  happen?

I would be making the package from the desktop installation that I have (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and distributing them to my servers via ftp or setting up a lunchpad account. The desktop is a stock install, and the only extra thing that I added was the lib2xml-dev so that I could compile php. The servers are also bare, only running 10 proccess, including nginx, and php-cgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and [build the source package](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/debian/build-from-source.jspx) from Debian testing; they currently [seem to be on PHP 5.4.4](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/php5.html).  (You may need to add some backports etc, though.)  Set up [your own repository](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository) and add it to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` on the servers.  You may need to build on a 11.04 box in order to be able to install on 11.04 (or play tricks with versioned dependencies).